# How to highlight text background color for duration?[android]

Tags: android, textview, highlighting, duration

I m making narrative app for children, every word is highlighted and prononounced. Some words take longer to prononounce, so i need to keep them highlighted for a bit longer.

```
    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
    TextView grandmom = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.grandmom) ;

    play.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                grandmom.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                return  true;
            }
        }
    });
```

the code above just highlights the word and **keeps it yellow forever**. How do I light it up for few milliseconds and then put back to normal?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AsyncTask` to play your sound.
Change background to yellow in `onPreExecute()`, and set it back to normal in `onPostExecute()`

That way you won't have to worry about time it takes to play the sound.

Comment: i have about 10 words per activity, can i run 10 asynctasks one after another?

Comment: Yes you can use as many of them as you want one after the another no problem.
Start next `AsyncTask` in first one's `onPostExecute()'.
Starting all of them in single place will start all of them together insted of one after another.

Answer (score 2):

Use Listeners on your `MediaPlayer` highlight on `OnPreparedListener` and back to normal on `OnCompletionListener`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TimerTask` ,schedule it so that it executes after a number of miliseconds and inside that task, after the time has elapsed, change the backGrounColor again to the original

You can also create a function that tells you how long to keep the the highlight on based on the lenght of the string and use that function to determine when to schdule the task of turning off the highlight